# SwiftUI Facebook Login - Mobile App STILL crashes after injecting Environment Object

Tags: swift, swiftui, facebook-login, inner-classes

I keep receiving the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type User found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for User may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

This is my code below for Facebook login via Swift. The specific code that causes it to crash is **self.user.isActive = true**. This code accesses my environment object User and changes the variable isActive to True, which triggers my Navigation Link and causes the DetailView to appear.

Given the error, I have tried multiple ways to inject the Environment variable:

1. I added it like this when I used login in the view: login().environmentObject(User()).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
2. I tried to initialize the Coordinator class with login as a parent, and then access the user.isActive variable via the parent relationship (i.e. self.parent.user.isActive = true) but this does not change the environment variable or push the screen.

3. I tried to use a navigation link directly in the Coordinator class but I cannot use the self.user.isActive as a binding bool.

````
struct login : UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<login>) -> FBLoginButton {

        let button = FBLoginButton()
        button.permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        button.delegate = context.coordinator
        return button
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<login>) {

//        if self.userDefault.bool(forKey: Constants.UserDefaults.currentUser) {self.user.isActive = true}
        
    }

    func activateLogin(){

                   if self.userDefault.bool(forKey: Constants.UserDefaults.currentUser)
                   { self.user.isActive = true }

                   }

    
    
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate {
        @EnvironmentObject var user: User
        let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        var parent: login
        
        init(_ parent: login) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        
        func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
            
            if error != nil{

                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            if AccessToken.current != nil{

                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)

                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res,er) in

                    if er != nil{
                        print((er?.localizedDescription)!)
                        return

                    }
                    print("success")
                        self.user.isActive = true
                        self.parent.user.isActive = true
                        self.userDefault.set(true, forKey: Constants.UserDefaults.currentUser)
                        self.userDefault.synchronize()

                }
            }
        }

        func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
            try! Auth.auth().signOut()
            print ("User logged out")

        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this request?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't have nice `@EnvironmentObject` set up for you in traditional UIKit views.

Maybe you can do it in views that conform to `UIViewRepresentable`, since it is meant to work with UIKit.

But I don't think a `class Coordinator: NSObject` is able to support `@EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: Hi Jim, 

Thanks for the reply. I have the Environment Object set up in Scene Delegate via:

let user = User()

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(user))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()

I also tried putting the environment object in the UIViewRepresentable (i.e. Login) and also as a parent

Comment: You probably need to show `User` definition. It needs to conform to `ObservableObject`. (also needs `@Published` for it to work)

Comment: Jim, please see my User definition. I need help with this issue because i've tried everything else on stack overflow.

Comment: Where is it? Also is there a particular reason to use inner class as coordinator? You may skip this problem by some design tweaking.